# Model is not passing value in MVC asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having basic problem in passing value at View through @Model, but unfortunately it is even not offering option for that. Data is not passing when I am hitting BACK from cities to states, it must bring me back to the states of that country, not all states.

Here is Controller

```
using MVCDemo.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MVCDemo.Controllers
{
public class CountryController : Controller
{


    public ActionResult GetCountries()
    {
        DatabaseContext databaseContext = new DatabaseContext();
        List<Country> countries = databaseContext.Countries.ToList();

        return View(countries);
    }

    public ActionResult GetStates(int CountryId)
    {
        DatabaseContext databaseContext = new DatabaseContext();
        List<State> states = databaseContext.States.Where(ctry => ctry.CountryId == CountryId).ToList();

        return View(states);
    }
    public ActionResult GetCities(int StateId)
    {
        DatabaseContext databaseContext = new DatabaseContext();
        List<City> cities = databaseContext.Cities.Where(st => st.StateId == StateId).ToList();

        return View(cities);
    }
}
}
```

Here are the Models

Country Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MVCDemo.Models

{
[Table("Countries")]
public class Country
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }

}
}
```

State Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MVCDemo.Models
{
    [Table("States")]
    public class State
    {
        public int StateId { get; set; }
        public string StateName { get; set; }
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

City Model

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MVCDemo.Models
{
    [Table("Cities")]
    public class City
    {
        public int CityId { get; set; }
        public string CityName { get; set; }
        public int StateId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here are Views.

Country View

```
    @using MVCDemo.Models;
@model IEnumerable<Country>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetCountries";
}

<h2>GetCountries</h2>
<ul>
@foreach(Country country in @Model)
{
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink(country.CountryName, "GetStates", "Country", new {@CountryId = country.CountryId}, null)

    </li>
}
    </ul>
```

State View

```
@using MVCDemo.Models;
@model IEnumerable <State>




@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetStates";
}

<h2>GetStates</h2>
<ul>
@foreach (State state in @Model)
{
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink(state.StateName, "GetCities", "Country", new {@StateId = state.StateId}, null)

    </li>
}
    </ul>
@Html.ActionLink("Back", "GetCountries")
```

View of Cities

```
@using MVCDemo.Models;
@model IEnumerable <City>



@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetCities";
}

<h2>GetCities</h2>
<ul>
@foreach (City city in @Model)
{
    <li>@city.CityName</li>
}
    </ul>
//Error comes here in following line. Model is not passing value of CountryId

@Html.ActionLink("Back to States", "GetStates", new { CountryId = @Model.CountryId })
```

Comment: What _is_ the URL generated by the "Back to States" ActionLink? And what does _"Model is not passing value of CountryId"_ mean exactly?

Comment: For a start, your Cities views is of `IEnumerable<City>` but you're using `@Model.CountryId` which isn't a property of IEnumerable.

Comment: Or: Create a proper CitiesViewModel with either 2x properties (list of cities, countryid) or inherit from IList<City> and add CountryId

Comment: @CodeCaster Compilation error. red line under the `@Model.CountryId`

Comment: @freedomn-m tables have foreign relationship .... states to country and cities to states, why would I add more relation to city table with country...

Comment: @QadeerMangrio you are not getting `@Model.First().StateID` ?

Comment: You have (parent)-to-(list of child) relationship (state gives list of cities), and you have (child)-to-(parent) (city gives parent state).  What you _do not have_ is (list of child)-to-(parent) (list of cities giving parent state (only the individual city has a state, not the whole list) so you add a new view model and pass both to the view.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

You're not able to retrieve the country with the model you've passed to the city-view. The only thing you have is an id of the state, not the full state object. Therefor you don't have the country id.

### Solution

Write a helper-class. The helper class could look like this.

```
class Helper
{
    public int GetCountryIdByCity(int cityId)
    {
        City city = databaseContext.States.Where(cty => cty.CityId == cityId).First();
        State state = databaseContext.States.Where(st => st.StateId == city.StateId).First();
        return databaseContext.Countries.Where(ctry => ctry.CountryId == state.CountryId).First().CountryId;
    }
}
```

That's very abstract and no error-handling implemented. You should do that by yourself.

After that you can update your view.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to States", "GetStates", new { CountryId = @Helper.GetCountryIdByCity(Model.First().CityId) })
```

Foreach foreign-key-relationship you can do the same.

Comment: Facing same as above comment to @AjayPunekar

Comment: Ah now I understand you want all states of the country in which the state of the displayed city is right?

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink("Back to previous page", null, null, null, new { href = Request.UrlReferrer})` done with this...working properly

Answer (score 0):

You View is `IEnumerable` strongly type view. And on controller side your are accepting only single item.

Use this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to States", "GetStates", new { CountryId = @Model.FirstOrDefault().CountryId })
```

Instead of

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to States", "GetStates", new { CountryId = @Model.CountryId })
```

Comment: this is not offering `@Model.FirstOrDefault().CountryId` becuase in the current model it has just `StateId` and `CityId`. I will have to use `CountryId` to bring the states of same country of those cities.